# Typescript bundling d.ts into 1 file with tsc for npm package - declaration file error

Tags: typescript, typescript-types, typescript-declarations, typescript-module-resolution

Trying to figure out how to bundle TS files into one JS file and one D.TS file. For example,

**src/foo.ts**

```
export function testFn() {
  return 123
}
```

**package.json**

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
"files": [ "/dist" ],
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "include": [ "src/foo.ts" ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ],
  "compilerOptions": {
     "rootDir": "src"
    ,"noImplicitAny": true
    ,"target": "es5"
    ,"module": "system"
    ,"moduleResolution": "node"
    ,"esModuleInterop": true
    ,"declaration": true
    ,"outFile": "./dist/index.js"
    ,"inlineSourceMap": true
    ,"inlineSources": true
  }
}
```

Compiled, I get the bundled system/es5 js which is fine, however I get ambient(?) declarations in the compiled+bundled index.d.ts file, which I'm guessing is why I'm receiving an error when I try to import it from another project (using npm link to test):

**dist/index.d.ts:**

```
declare module "foo" {
    export function testFn(): number;
}
```

**a-different-project/src/file.ts:**

```
import foo from "@repo/proj"
```

Error: **File '.../proj/dist/index.d.ts' is not a module**

Been stuck for a long time if anyone knows what's wrong-- Thanks for your help!